# How to import a rigged model into an other file?

Tags: linked-data, append

I downloaded a 3d model and it is rigged, it has parameters and a lot of things to it. And now I would like to use it in an Blender file I'm working on and it would be great if I could use the parameters, the rigging and everything in the other file.

[image: the model itself]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to link/append the top-level "Zelda" collection into any file without issues.

Go to file → Link (or Append if you prefer a full copy), navigate to your blend file, then in its Collections folder, and select "Zelda".
It should be able to get everything. If for some reason you are unable to get the custom UI, then just link/append whatever script generates if by finding if in the "Texts" file folder, then execute the script from the text editor.

If you chose to link your asset, you will need to make a "library override" in order to be able to make changes on it, such as animating.
To do so, select it in object mode and go to Object → Relations → Make Library Override

Comment: When you have linked the collection (*Zelda*) then you need to do an *Object > Relations > Make Library Override...* on it to make the rig work.

Comment: Indeed, I should have mentioned that. Thanks for the reminder!